# how to convert bits to 0 without changing the 0's to 1's

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I'm currently studying for an assembly test. The test is based around a 32x32 LED simulator, each LED in the simulator represents 32 bits, with it being on if the bit is 1 or off if it is 0.
[image: Here is the Visual]

The user is supposed to select a row between 0-31. When they do the LED's switch from on to off one by one starting from the left-hand side.

Here is my code so far:

```
.data
row         DWORD   0
y           DWORD   80000000h
message     BYTE    'Enter in a row',0
caption     BYTE    'Welcome to CA296',0

.code
    main:nop

        invoke version
        invoke setPattern, 7
        invoke readIntegerWithMessage, ADDR message
        mov row, eax
L1:     invoke readRow, row
        mov ecx,y
        xor eax,ecx
        invoke writeRow, row, eax
        shr y,1
        jmp L1
```

As you can probably guess all this does is just reverse the bits so that the off ones become on and the on ones become off, how do I only target the LED's that are on?

Comment: Use `eax = eax & ~ecx` instead of `eax = eax ^ ecx`.

Comment: could you explain what ~ecx is? Apologies.

Comment: `~` is bitwise NOT.

Comment: The `~` operator is bitwise-NOT in C.